# Partial specialization with a non-template class which is inherited from a template class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, partial-specialization

### Example 1

If we have `Base` and `Derived` classes

```
class Base
{};
class Derived : public Base
{};
```

and a template class

```
template <class T, class Enabler=void>
class Partialy
{
public:
    void say()
    {
        std::cout << "Partialy Default" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

We can write a partial specialization next way:

```
template <class T>
class Partialy<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of< Base, T >::value>::type>
{
public:
    void say()
    {
        std::cout << "Partialy special" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

**Example 1** will work OK. (Full code: http://ideone.com/4FyrD )

### Example 2

If only I make `Base` class template one:

```
template <class T>
class BaseTpl
{};
class DerivedTpl : public BaseTpl<int>
{};
```

The next partial specializetion don't work:

```
template <class T, class Ta>
class Partialy<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of< BaseTpl<Ta>, T >::value>::type>
{
public:
    void say()
    {
        std::cout << "Partialy special with TPL" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

**Example 2** won't compile
The compiler throws an error `"template parameters not used in partial specialization:"` (Full code: http://ideone.com/gZ6J2 )

### Question

***So the question is. Is there any way to write partial specializaion which would work for all classes which are derived from `BaseTpl`.***

The list of classes for which the specialization shold work:

```
class A1 : public BaseTpl<int>
class A2 : public BaseTpl<std::string>
class A3 : public BaseTpl<vector<int> >
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it, it is impossible for the compiler to match the `Ta` against any type. Imagine you had this:

```
class DerivedTpl : public BaseTpl<int>, public BaseTpl<char>
{};
```

What type will `Ta` be when it tries to match?

For your particular problem, one solution is to introduce an all-encompassing base class above `BaseTpl`:

```
class BaseNonTpl {};

template <class T>
class BaseTpl : BaseNonTpl
{};
```

Then, modify the partial specialisation to look for that base class instead.

```
template <class T>
class PartialyTpl<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of< BaseNonTpl, T >::value>::type>
```

That way, the compiler doesn't have to try and figure out what base class you meant to use.

Comment: Thanks I have forgotten about multiple inheritance.

Comment: What about `class A : public BaseNonTpl` case ?

Comment: @PiotrNycz: Don't do that :-)